# ¿Que quiere decir el punto en una ruta en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Por ejemplo en este código veo que route esta asi: "pedidos3.create"

```
{!!Form::open(['route'=>'pedidos3.create','method'=>'GET','class'=>'form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask','name'=>'sumar']) !!}
```

pero en la ruta únicamente está así:

```
Route::resource('pedidos3', 'PedidosController@create');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El punto como tal no quiere decir nada en especial, es una convención de Laravel para separar el nombre del conjunto de rutas o del controlador y la acción que realiza el método. Pero puede ser "casa.auto" o "micasa" y también va a funcionar, es solo un nombre que se define junto con la ruta.

Al utilizar `Route::resource` le estás diciendo a Laravel que cree todo el conjunto de rutas relacionadas con CRUD.

Si haces `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotosController');`, Laravel generará las siguientes rutas:

```
Verbo       URI                     Acción  Nombre ruta
GET         /photos                 index   photos.index
GET         /photos/create          create  photos.create
POST        /photos                 store   photos.store
GET         /photos/{photo}         show    photos.show
GET         /photos/{photo}/edit    edit    photos.edit
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo}         update  photos.update
DELETE      /photos/{photo}         destroy photos.destroy
```

La forma correcta de utilizar Route::resource es sin especificar el método, simplemente el controlador:

```
Route::resource('pedidos3', 'PedidosController');
```

Toda la información la encuentras en la documentación:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: ¿Como sabe laravel  que método deberá utilizar en el controlador si no se especifica en la ruta?

Comment: Revisa la tabla que está en la respuesta, en la columna Acción

Comment: Digamos que si se pone pedidos3.create laravel sobreentiende un GET /pedidos3/create y el metodo que se utilizaria es create, son como palabras reservadas?

Comment: Si se pone en dónde?

Comment: En la ruta del formulario {!!Form::open(['route'=>'pedidos3.create','method'=>'GET','class'=>'form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask','name'=>'sumar']) !!}

Comment: No son palabras reservadas, no entiendo a qué te refieres, simplemente así se definen las rutas cuando usas `Route::resource`. Si deseas definir la ruta a un método distinto, lo puedes hacer también, bien sea con el parámetro except o no utilizando Resourceful routes.

Comment: A lo que me refiero un ejemplo si la ruta  es Route::resource('pedidos',             'PedidosController'); . En este caso no se especifica el metodo, por ende laravel sobreentiende que el metodo que ira a buscar es index?

Comment: La verdad no entiendo lo que quieres saber, en la respuesta está todo bien explicado. Route::resource define un CONJUNTO de rutas, y en la columna acción están los métodos que va a buscar en el controlador cada una de dichas rutas. Si creas una ruta usando Route::get o Route::post o el verbo que sea, estás creando UNA SOLA ruta, pero con Route::resource creas SIETE rutas.

Comment: Gracias Shaz, realmente no era la respuesta, pero me diste una idea para lo que yo quería entender.